# Implementing loading image in WinrT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

How i can implement a default loading image to my image control while the time of image loading. ie need to display the loading image initially and after the actual image loads i need to set that image as my image source. I windows phone i implemented the same with the help of LowProfileImageLoader class. But in windows 8 how i can implement the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy to do this in a Windows Store app by using the [async functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464924.aspx).  You would set your image source to your loading image (maybe using the [ms-appx protocol and loading it from your package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322%28v=win.10%29.aspx)) while you use a [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28VS.110%29.aspx) to download the larger image for example.  Here is a [sample on how to use HttpClient asynchronously](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664).

Per comment:  You can use the [ProgressRing class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.progressring.aspx) and change to the image when you get the ImageOpened event.  S[ee this example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/536a3d52-0c9f-4875-8ad5-991a9eab17c8).

Comment: For the case of loading a singe image it is ok. I am talking about a GridView, And also i placed my image inside a template.